# How can I automatically download all images from all imported posts, place them on my new host, and replace all the links

Tags: plugins, posts, images

First some background information.

I have an old website (**not** *wordpress*) => https://www.carnaval-radio.nl from now on, I will call this **old**.

I have a new website (*in wordpress*) => https://carnaval.bynick.nl from now on, I will call this **new**.

I have imported all posts of the *old* website through an RSS feed into my *new* website. The links to all the images inside those posts remain linking to the old website.

- The images on the old website are served trough an *axd* file
  https://carnavalsradio.nl/image.axd?picture=2020%2F2%2F86386253_2945403745507075_1513521371026554880_n.jpg
  (So I can't just change the path everywhere)

Is there some kind of plugin that let's me download all the images, replace all the links in all posts, and serve those images trough my *new* website? Or are there perhaps other ways to do this?

Comment: Yes, there are plugins that do this. First one I found is [Auto Upload Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/), from [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-import-external-images-in-wordpress/), although I haven't tried it myself to vouch for it. There are probably more,

Comment: @Rup old site is not wordpress as I stated.

Comment: Oh missed that - sorry. There are importers from many other CMSes too though.

Comment: It's not build on a popular CMS. It's BlogEngine.NET (2011 version). Anyway `Auto Upload Images` is what I need. Why not add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins that do this, e.g. [Auto Upload Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/) (found in [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-import-external-images-in-wordpress/)). I haven't tried it myself to recommend it.

You're migrating from BlogEngine.NET. There is also an old BlogML importer plugin to migrate directly from BlogEngine.NET (which produces BlogML exports), but [the copy in the main WordPress directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogml-importer/) hasn't been updated in years and is no longer available to download. There is a fixed up version here: http://spacefold.com/colin/morethanfour/2020/08/06/migrating-from-blogengine/ however the process does also require manually fixing up image paths.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!